# Adding functions to a ListBuffer then executing the functions

Tags: scala

I'm attempting to create a `Listbuffer` of functions and then execute each function in the `Listbuffer`

Here is my code :

```
object FunctionList {

  def f(a : String , b : String) = {
    a+b
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val fl: ListBuffer[(String, String => Int)] = ListBuffer();

    val f1 = FunctionList.f("1" , "2")
    val f2 = FunctionList.f("1" , "2")

    fl += f1;

  }
}
```

Above code fails to compile and returns error :

```
cannot resolve symbol +=
```

How to add functions of type `(a : String , b : String) => String` to a `Listbuffer` for later execution ?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. There are many, many, many problems with your code (too many to list), but the problem you claim is not one of them.

Comment: First your **ListBuffer** does not expect a **Function** of two arguments, but a **Tuple** of one **String** and a **Function** from one **String** to an **Int**. Second, your **Function** `f` does not return an **Int**, but a **String**. Finally, your variables `f1` & `f2` are not **Functions**, but **Strings**. Thus, everything in your code is wrong _(without counting the unnecessary use of mutation and non-idiomatic syntax)_. Can you describe what you are trying to do? So we can propose a solution. If you only want to have a list of functions and apply them latter, then see Mario's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions are first class values and can be added to collections like any other value. For example

```
val f1 = (a : String , b : String) => a + b
val f2 = (a : String , b : String) => b + a
List(f1, f2)
```

outputs

```
res0: List[(String, String) => String] = List(<function>$$Lambda$914/16756436@46d68049)
```

To apply them map over the collection like so

```
List(f1, f2).map(f => f.apply("foo", "bar"))
List(f1, f2).map(f => f("foo", "bar"))
List(f1, f2).map(_("foo", "bar"))
```

which outputs

```
res1: List[String] = List(foobar, barfoo)
res2: List[String] = List(foobar, barfoo)
res3: List[String] = List(foobar, barfoo)
```

Note how we can [`apply`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Function2.html#apply(v1:T1,v2:T2):R) function either explicitly or implicitly.

Answer (score 1):

In Scala functions are a first-class value, that is functions can be passed as arguments to other functions, and functions can return other functions.

```
object FunctionList {

  val anonymousFunc: (String, String) => String = (a: String, b: String) => a + b

  def defMethod(a: String, b: String): String = {
     a + b
  }

 def addition(f: (String, String) => String, a: String, b: String): String = f(a, b)

def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
//Function List
val functionList = new ListBuffer[(String, String) => String]()
functionList += FunctionList.anonymousFunc
functionList += FunctionList.defMethod
println(functionList)

//Execute Functions
val op = functionList.map(func => {
  func("1", "2")
})
println(op)

//value List,
val fl = new ListBuffer[String]()

fl += anonymousFunc("1", "2")
fl += defMethod("1", "2")
fl += defMethod(anonymousFunc("2", "3"), "2")
fl += addition(anonymousFunc, "1", "0")
println(fl)
}
}
```

Comment: Ya I have edited defFunc to defMethod. Thanks @JörgWMittag

Answer (score 1):

You can also write following generic function:

```scala
import scala.collection.mutable

class FunctionHandlers[I, O] {
  private val handlers: mutable.Buffer[I => O] = mutable.Buffer.empty

  def add(handler: I => O): Unit = handlers += handler

  def execute(input: I): List[O] = handlers.map(f => f(input)).toList
}

// ========== example ===========
object FunctionList {

  def f(a: (String, String)): String = a._1 + a._2

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val handlers = new FunctionHandlers[(String, String), String]();

    handlers.add(f)
    handlers.add(f)

    val results = handlers.execute(("1", "2"))
    results.foreach(println)
  }
}
// ======== Output ==========
// 12
// 12
```